# Reading values from a file in Java

Tags: java, graph

So I'm building a graph to find the shortest distance between two points using Warshall's algorithm. Here's a small part of my code:

```
public Edge( In in ) {
        System.out.println("here1");
        String location = in.readString();
        System.out.println("here1b");
        int V = in.readInt();
        System.out.println("here1c");
        dist = new int [V][V];
    System.out.println("here1d");
    int n = in.readInt();
```

And here's the input:

```
3
4 
A 0 0 0 
B 5 0 0 
C 5 5 0 
D 0 5 0 
2 
A C
C D
```

Now the output looks like this.

```
case 1:
here1
here1b
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In.readInt(In.java:322)
    at Edge.<init>(Edge.java:10)
    at Edge.main(Edge.java:51)
```

So the exception happens when I do `in.readInt();`. Here's my main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
      In in = new In( args[0] );
      int T = in.readInt();
      for (int t=1; t<=T; t++) {
         System.out.println("Case " + t + ":") ;
         Edge w = new Edge( in );
         int Q = in.readInt();
         for (int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
            String p1s = in.readString();
            String p2s = in.readString();
         }
      }
```

here's my entire edge class:

```
public Edge( In in ) {
    String location = in.readString();
    System.out.println(location);
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        System.out.println(in.readInt());
        dist = new int [V][V];
        int n = in.readInt();
        int [][] G = new int [n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                dist[i][j] = in.readInt();
            }
        }
        }

        /*int E = in.readInt();
        for (int l = 0; l < E; l++){
            int i = in.readInt();
            int j = in.readInt();
        }
        */
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    dist[i][j] = Math.min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]);
                }
            }
        }
       }
```

And here's what I'm using for the `In` class: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/In.java.html. So how come `in.readInt();` is not working?

Comment: But it's supposed to go through each line and only the first letter is a string and the rest are supposed to be ints.

Comment: I'm assuming you're giving in a file location as args[0]?
Then you are reading the first int (3). After that you are reading a String in this case it would be 4 interpreted as string. The next time you try to read an int you encounter the "A" and your In class throws an exception.

Comment: I guess Java is supposed to read each value from the file and I'm using in.readInt() because all values besides the first ones are supposed to be ints.

Comment: So then how do I go through each value?

Comment: what is the `In` type in `Edge( In in )` ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: From the javadoc for Scanner class "Whitespace is not significant in the above regular expressions." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Integer-regex

Comment: @user306848 Since I hadn't read `In` at the time, it was a "guess"

Comment: @Chase I'm not sure what the meaning of your data is, but, you're reading the first `int` (`3`), then trying to read `4` (as a `String`) and `A` as a `int` (because of the way the reads are laid out). When I read the second `int`, I was about to get `A`, `0` before it failed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with you code a little, you're reading the first `int` (`3`), then trying to read the edge data, which reads in `4`, `A`, but because `A` is not an `int` and it breaks.

If I change your code to something more like...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    In in = new In("Data.txt");
    int T = in.readInt(); // 3
    int something = in.readInt(); // 4
    for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
        System.out.println("Case " + t + ":");
        Edge w = new Edge(in);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Edge {

    public Edge(In in) {
        String location = in.readString();
        System.out.println(location);
        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
            System.out.println(in.readInt());
        }
    }

}
```

It prints out something like...

```
Case 1:
A
0
0
0
Case 2:
B
5
0
0
Case 3:
C
5
5
0
```

I don't have enough information about what all the structure of the file to fully correct your code, but you need to make sure you're reading it correctly.  You should also use `System.out.println` to print the data as you read, so you can check what you're actually reading and a debugger to step through the code so you can inspect the values of your variables more closely

Comment: Ok I updated my code to show the entire edge class. So what can I use instead of in.readInt(); because I don't know what to replace that with.

Comment: Just read the first two `int` values from the file header ... I'm not sure what the file format is, so I'm just guessing